# What is the difference between the StAX Cursor API and Iterator API?

Tags: java, xml, stax

I came across two different codes for parsing a file with `StAX`. A quick googling told me that there are 2 ways to parse : using ***cursor API*** and using ***iterator API***. Please tell me the difference between the two and which one is easier to use from developer point of view.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're most likely to find the answer in the StAX API sections within the Java Web Services Developer Pack tutorial or [Java EE 5 tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbec.html#bnbej). Both of them contain the same information that I am reproducing below:

> **Comparing Cursor and Iterator APIs**
>
> Before choosing between the cursor and
>   iterator APIs, you should note a few
>   things that you can do with the
>   iterator API that you cannot do with
>   cursor API:
>
> - Objects created from the XMLEvent subclasses are immutable, and can be
>     used in arrays, lists, and maps, and
>     can be passed through your
>     applications even after the parser has
>     moved on to subsequent events.
> - You can create subtypes of XMLEvent that are either completely
>     new information items or extensions of
>     existing items but with additional
>     methods.
> - You can add and remove events from an XML event stream in much simpler
>     ways than with the cursor API.
>
> Similarly, keep some general
>   recommendations in mind when making
>   your choice:
>
> - If you are programming for a particularly memory-constrained
>     environment, like J2ME, you can make
>     smaller, more efficient code with the
>     cursor API.
> - If performance is your highest priority--for example, when creating
>     low-level libraries or
>     infrastructure--the cursor API is more
>     efficient.
> - If you want to create XML processing pipelines, use the iterator
>     API.
> - If you want to modify the event stream, use the iterator API.
> - If you want to your application to be able to handle pluggable processing
>     of the event stream, use the iterator
>     API.
> - In general, if you do not have a strong preference one way or the
>     other, using the iterator API is
>     recommended because it is more
>     flexible and extensible, thereby
>     "future-proofing" your applications.

The iterator API although recommended is slower than the cursor API, as the cursor does not need to remember the previous nodes that it had parsed; it provides forward-only parsing of XML documents and does not have the overhead of construction of `XMLEvent` objects. Apparently, [a benchmark](http://www.cs.uku.fi/~kilpelai/RDK11/lectures/StAX.ppt) has indicated that SAX might turn out to be better at parsing large documents compared to StAX; you might want to verify if you can reproduce the results of the benchmark for your data-sets.

Comment: Update on the large document issue. The link you presented was from a 2011 course on Structured-Document Processing Languages. I note that your comment was from 2011, but now it's 2014. I haven't done new benchmarks, but looking carefully at the course info at your link, it appears that much of the performance problem was due to a memory leak when DOCTYPE was used. Given that the problem was clearly understood 3 years ago, seems like it would have been fixed by now. Also; the StAX Cursor API had best overall performance even back then - even held up very well with larger file sizes.

Comment: I know that this is an old answer but still curious: Any code sample that iterator API remembers the previous nodes? I sould not find any proof about that.

Answer (score -3):

If you are not parsing long XML files, then you could simply use JDOM, JDOM loads the entire XML in memory and is slower, but it is very easy to use.

[jdom](http://www.jdom.org/)

Comment: @oscarMk- JDOM is out of question for the same reason u mentioned- **i am using a file with size > 200MB**